# Why do I get "double free or corruption"?

Tags: c++, serialization, memory-leaks, runtime-error

I am trying to serialize a struct, but the program crashed with:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./unserialization: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000cf8010 ***
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

struct Dummy
{
    std::string name;
    double height;
};

template<typename T>
class Serialization
{
    public:
        static unsigned char* toArray (T & t)
        {
            unsigned char *buffer = new unsigned char [ sizeof (T) ];
            memcpy ( buffer , &t , sizeof (T) );
            return buffer;
        };

        static T fromArray ( unsigned char *buffer )
        {
            T t;
            memcpy ( &t , buffer , sizeof (T) );
            return t;
        };
};

int main ( int argc , char **argv ) 
{
    Dummy human;
    human.name = "Someone";
    human.height = 11.333;

    unsigned char *buffer = Serialization<Dummy>::toArray (human);

    Dummy dummy = Serialization<Dummy>::fromArray (buffer);

    std::cout << "Name:" << dummy.name << "\n" << "Height:" << dummy.height << std::endl;

    delete buffer;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a `std::vector<T>` in place of `new T[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two problems with this code:

1. You are invoking undefined behavior by `memcpy`ing a `struct` containing a `std::string` into another location.  If you `memcpy` a class that isn't just a pure struct (for example, a `std::string`), it can cause all sorts of problems.  In this particular case, I think that part of the problem might be that `std::string` sometimes stores an internal pointer to a buffer of characters containing the actual contents of the string.  If you `memcpy` the `std::string`, you bypass the string's normal copy constructor that would duplicate the string.  Instead, you now have two different instances of `std::string` sharing a pointer, so when they are destroyed they will both try to delete the character buffer, causing the bug you're seeing.  There is no easy fix for this other than to not do what you're doing.  It's just fundamentally unsafe.
2. You are allocating memory with `new[]`, but deleting it with `delete`.  You should use the array deleting operator `delete[]` to delete this memory, since using regular `delete` on it will result in undefined behavior, potentially causing this crash.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Basically, his `Serialization` class needs a sprinkling of `enable_if<is_pod<T> >`.  Or the new `is_trivially_copyable`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not valid to use `memcpy()` with a data element of type `std::string` (or really, any non-[POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) data type). The `std::string` class stores the *actual* string data in a dynamically-allocated buffer. When you `memcpy()` the contents of a `std::string` around, you are obliterating the pointers allocated internally and end up accessing memory that has been already freed.

You could make your code work by changing the declaration to:

```
struct Dummy
{
    char name[100];
    double height;
};
```

However, that has the disadvantages of a fixed size `name` buffer. If you want to maintain a dynamically sized `name`, then you will need to have a more sophisticated `toArray` and `fromArray` implementation that doesn't do straight memory copies.

Answer (score 0):

You're copying the `string`'s internal buffer in the `toArray` call. When deserializing with `fromArray` you "create" a second string in `dummy`, which thinks it owns the same buffer as `human`.

Answer (score 0):

std::string probably contains a *pointer* to a buffer that contains the string data.  When you call toArray (human), you're memcpy()'ing the Dummy class's string, including the pointer to the string's data.  Then when you create a new Dummy object by memcpy()'ing directly into it, you've created a new string object with the same pointer to string data as the first object.  Next thing you know, dummy gets destructed and the copy of the pointer gets destroyed, then human gets destructed and BAM, you got a double free.

Generally, copying objects using memcpy like this will lead to all sorts of problems, like the one you've seen.  Its probably just going to be the tip of the ice berg.  Instead, you might consider explicitly implementing some sort of marshalling function for each class you want to serialize.

Alternatively, you might look into json libraries for c++, which can serialize things into a convenient text based format.  JSON protocols are commonly used with custom network protocols where you want to serialize objects to send over a socket.